# Angular - Render component present inside another module on root url

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular8

I have `Angular 8` application. I have divided my app into different modules.

- AppModule
- HomeModule
- User Module

I am trying to load the HomeComponent present inside HomeModule on the root url ('`/`')

app.component.html

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './module/common/header/header.component';
import { HomeModule } from './module/home/home/home.module';
//& so on.


@NgModule({
declarations: [
  AppComponent,
  LogoComponent,
  MenuComponent,
  SearchComponent,
  SignComponent,
  HeaderComponent
],
imports: [
 BrowserModule,
 AppRoutingModule,
 HomeModule,
 UserModule
],
providers: [],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.routing.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './module/home/home/home.component';
import { HomeModule } from './module/home/home/home.module';

const routes: Routes = [
{ path : '', component : HomeComponent, loadChildren: ()=> 
import('../app/module/home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule)}
];

@NgModule({
 imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
 exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

home.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
 declarations:
    [
        HomeComponent
    ],
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HomeRoutingModule

],
exports: [
    HomeComponent
],
 providers: []
})

export class HomeModule { }
```

But when running the application, it is throwing the below error.

> Component HomeComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module

What is causing this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you made a mistake in app.routing.ts

> const routes: Routes = [ { path : '', component : HomeComponent,
>   loadChildren: ()=>  import('../app/module/home/home.module').then(mod
>   => mod.HomeModule)} ];

The correct code should be:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path : '', loadChildren: ()=> import('../app/module/home/home.module').then(mod => mod.HomeModule)}
];
```

Then create a home.routing.ts and code like this way:

```
const routes: Routes = [
{ path : '', component : HomeComponent }
];
```

As you don't need to use it in any other module and it obviously shouldn't, remove HomeComponent from exports:

> ```
> exports: [
>     HomeComponent
> ],
> ```

this code should be removed.

**Explanation:**
Because in app component, we load the module lazily, not component. So, we shouldn't specify homeComponent in app.routing.ts.

Every module should have own routing. As home is a module, it should have a home.routing.ts and we need to specify which route it should go when loading home module. So, we specify the homecomponent in home routing.

Comment: Absolutely Right, Thank You